# What is the API way to edit a 'floating' row in Ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid

There is below api to edit a rowIndex.  But what is the API to edit a floatingTopRow or floatingBottomRow in ag-grid.  I use ag-grid-enterprise evaluation.

```
this.gridOptions.api.startEditingCell({
  rowIndex: 10, colKey:'column_name'
});
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is a direct way in the api right now. [Here is a feature request to enhance this function.](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/1326) However on that page there is a possible workaround that you could use. Here it is:

```
let gridCell = api.getFocusedCell();
(<any>api).rowRenderer.startEditingCell(gridCell, null, null);
```

This workaround seems to hinge on the premise that you have selected/highlighted a cell first, then clicked a button to allow you to edit it. Alternatively you can predefine cells like so:

```
var gridCell = {
    column: {} // the column of the cell that needs to be edited 
               // use gridOptions.columnApi.getColumn('column_name') to get the column,
    floating: "" // either "top" or "bottom" or null,
    rowIndex: 0 // integer value of row to edit
}
```